# MacOsX Sierra (Cocoa pod) : sh: line 1: 4169 Bus error: 10 /usr/bin/xcrun clang 2>&1

Tags: macos, cocoapods

When I type **pod init**, i got this message:

```
sh: line 1:  4169 Bus error: 10           /usr/bin/xcrun clang 2>&1
```

I have also this error message when I type : **brew doctor** (`sh: line 1:  4389 Bus error: 10           /usr/bin/xcrun clang 2>&1`)

And when I type :**pod repo update --verbose** i got the same :

```
sh: line 1:  4405 Bus error: 10           /usr/bin/xcrun clang 2>&1
```

I think it comes from **clang**, because when I just type **clang** i got :

```
Bus error: 10
```

Anyone has a idea of what it is wrong ?

Thanks !

PS: I tried to remove all  /Users/User_Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/. folders and it does nothing to solve my problem

Comment: Have you upgraded your OS since you installed Xcode? You may need to update your Xcode and maybe re-install Xcode commandline tools.

Comment: Ok thanks , I'll test it !